# Running PowerShell Script From A Batch File Using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, process, batch-file

i have a powershell script file, and a bat file, the bat file runs the script, so when i double click
the bat file the script get executed.
in my code i do the following:

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@batchfilename + ".bat");  
            Process processToStart = new Process();  
            processToStart.StartInfo = info;  
            processToStart.Start();
```

the batch gets executed and the powershell scripts starts, but it crashes telling me somthing about policy issue.
allthoug my policy is unrestrected, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set Execution Policy to unrestricted [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx).

Execution Policies (From the above MSDN link)

> - Restricted - No scripts can be run. Windows PowerShell can be used only in interactive mode.
> - AllSigned - Only scripts signed by a trusted publisher can be run.
> - RemoteSigned - Downloaded scripts must be signed by a trusted publisher before they can be run.
> - Unrestricted - No restrictions; all Windows PowerShell scripts can be run.

For 64 bit system, it needs to be set separately for x86, and x64.

[PowerShell 32 and 64 bit have different execution policy settings](http://simon-hughes.blogspot.in/2011/05/setting-powershell-execution-policy.html)

Comment: For both x86 and x64? If so, try to run VS as administrator

Comment: your saying that if my computer is a 64bit, than i need to set both of the operation system types?

Comment: Yes. if you have 64bit Windows, you need to set executionpolicy in `c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` (64bit PS, default one) AND `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` (32bit, may be called by some programs).

Comment: You could try modifying the batch file so that you're passing `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` into Powershell. Then you don't need to modify the system settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell.exe c:\FULL_PATH\send.ps1
```

Comment: And... to what question is this answer?